# extracting specific data from string

Tags: python

I have this string below, from which I need to get specific configuration for respective interfaces, example I need to be able to parse to get.

```
interface Loopback0
  ip address 1.1.1.1/32
  no shutdown
  isis enable 2222
  isis passive
```

or be able to get

```
interface Management0
  no sflow enable
  ip address 1.1.1.2/31
  no shutdown
  isis enable 2222
  isis passive
```

The number of lines under an interface can vary.

The string is:

```
[hostname router\r\n!\r\ninterface Loopback0\r\n  ip address 1.1.1.1/32\r\n  no shutdown\r\n isis enable 2222\r\n  isis passive\r\n!\r\nvrf definition MGMT\r\n  rd 200:200\r\n!\r\n!\r\nvrf definition VRF_DDOS\r\n  rd 2222:100\r\n  description VRF_DDOS\r\n!\r\n!\r\n interface ethernet1/1\r\n  no sflow enable\r\n ip address 1.1.1.2/31\r\n  no shutdown\r\n isis enable 2222\r\n  isis passive\r\n!\r\nvrf definition MGMT\r\n  rd 200:200\r\n!\r\n!\r\nvrf definition VRF_DDOS\r\n  rd 2222:100\r\n  description VRF_DDOS\r\n!\r\n!\r\n ]
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://pythex.org/and learn how to use RegEx

If you enter your string into the exmaple text and use (\d.\d.\d.\d/\d\d) as the pattern it will collect every IP address.

```
import re

ip_address = re.findall(r'(\d.\d.\d.\d/\d\d)', string)

print(ip_address)
>>> 1.1.1.1/32, 1.1.1.2/31
```

Alternatively if your output is always the same, you could split the string at '\' and get the index of each item.

example:

```
feedback = "[hostname router\r\n!\r\ninterface Loopback0\r\n ip address 1.1.1.1/32\r\n no shutdown\r\n isis " \
              "enable 2222\r\n isis passive\r\n!\r\nvrf definition MGMT\r\n rd 200:200\r\n!\r\n!\r\nvrf definition" \
              " VRF_DDOS\r\n rd 2222:100\r\n description VRF_DDOS\r\n!\r\n!\r\n interface ethernet1/1\r\n no sflow " \
              "enable\r\n ip address 1.1.1.2/31\r\n no shutdown\r\n isis enable 2222\r\n isis passive\r\n!\r\nvrf " \
              "definition MGMT\r\n rd 200:200\r\n!\r\n!\r\nvrf definition VRF_DDOS\r\n rd 2222:100\r\n description " \
              "VRF_DDOS\r\n!\r\n!\r\n ]".replace('\r\n','').split(' ')

print(feedback[2:6])

output >>> ['Loopback0', 'ip', 'address', '1.1.1.1/32']
```